# sed adding string within parentheses where only number is present

Tags: sed

Let say we have this sentence:

input:

```
This is some string (234) and so on
```

output:

```
This is some string (page 234) and so on
```

Question is how to add "page" when number is find, numbers are with parentheses.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show your attempt, we can help improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `sed`:

```
sed 's/(\([[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]*\))/(page \1)/g' file
```

```
$ cat file
This (is) some string (234) and so on
(This is some string ( 1324) and so on
This is some string (text) and so on
```

```
$ sed 's/(\([[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]*\))/(page \1)/g' file
This (is) some string (page 234) and so on
(This is some string (page  1324) and so on
This is some string (text) and so on
```

Comment: FYI: `()` -> `(page )`. `[[:digit:]]\+` to fix.

Comment: Thanks @MannyD. Good catch. I almost made it through without getting detected. `:P`

Comment: @jaypal I know this could be done by ease using back reference. Here is a good example on it. :)

Comment: what is difference between [[:digit:]]\+ and [[:digit:]]* @jaypal

Comment: @josifoski `[[:digit:]]\+` will match 1 or more digits. `[[:digit:]]*` will match 0 or more digits.

Comment: solution can be improved with putting \\( only to digits \\)

Comment: @josifoski Sorry I did not follow you. Can you please elaborate? We are focusing only on digits that may or may not have spaces around them. `[[:digit:]]` is a character class that only looks for digits. As you can see from the last unchanged line.

Comment: @jaypal well \1 is what is catched with \\( and \\) as i understood, so just only triming number

Comment: @josifoski Yes absolutely, however that would also normalize all multiple spaces to single space. If that is not a concern, then sure by all means go with that one. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in so many ways and is so simple that you should have found at least one solution using google.  Here is some very simple.

```
sed 's/(/(page /g' file
This is some string (page 234) and so on
```

To test for number you can do some like this:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($(i%2)~"^[0-9]+$") $i="page "$i;printf "%s%s%s",(i%2==1 && i!=1?")":""),$i,(i%2 && i!=NF?"(":"")}print ""}' file
This is some string (page 234) and so on
```

---

Here is a `gnu awk` based on jaypals regex.

```
awk '{print gensub(/\(([[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*)\)/,"(page \\1)","")}' file
This is some string (page 234) and so on (not this)45(nor this) more
```

Comment: what about if not number there, for example (string)

Comment: @josifoski I am sure that this can be done more simple.

Comment: sed preffered, but tnx anyway :)

Comment: @josifoski It will be very hard to make a 100% foolproof solution.  If the line contains an open parentheses, this will fail.

Comment: @josifoski Lasted `awk` should work the same way as jaypals solution.